# How I can change bit depth of a image with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, images

I want to change a image of 24 bit depth to a 32 bit depth using ffmpeg

Comment: In order to achieve what? Are you trying to 'gain information' or are you wanting to add an empty transparency channel? What file format?

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg` might not be the best tool here; [`imagemagick`](https://imagemagick.org/) should be better suited to this purpose.
Its [`-depth`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#depth) option should be what is needed.

If for any reason `ffmpeg` has to be used, the [`pix_fmt`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-Video-options) option or the [`format`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format-1) filter might be of help.